# HornetQ: Cannot use connection factory when the server is acting as a backup

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss7.x, hornetq

I have live-backup HornetQ 2 servers cluster sharing a store on a NAS, i have applications from outside connecting to the cluster and i can see that everything is working: when live server goes down and the backup start as a live one, my applications are switching to this new server without any problem.

HornetQ is used as a part of JBoss AS 7 server, where i have other applications too that are connecting to the HornetQ cluster, they are using the same connection factory used by other application from outside the cluster, here's the used connection factory:

```
<jms-connection-factories>
    <connection-factory name="hornetq">
        <connectors>
            <connector-ref connector-name="node1-live"/>
            <connector-ref connector-name="node2-backup"/>
        </connectors>
        <entries>
            <entry name="java:/jms/ConnectionFactory"/>
            <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/ConnectionFactory"/>
        </entries>
    </connection-factory>
</jms-connection-factories>
```

and here's my connectors definitions:

```
<connectors>
    <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
    <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
    <connector name="node1-live">
        <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory</factory-class>
        <param key="host" value="10.10.10.1"/>
        <param key="port" value="5445"/>
        <param key="use-nio" value="true"/>
    </connector>
    <connector name="node2-backup">
        <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory</factory-class>
        <param key="host" value="10.10.10.2"/>
        <param key="port" value="5445"/>
        <param key="use-nio" value="true"/>
    </connector>
</connectors>
```

The problem i'm having is no node2 (backup node), it seems that when it's running as backup, the HornetQ messaging subsystem is not loaded and in consequence, the factories and connectors are not exposed to the applications hosted on node2's JBoss AS.

Am looking for a way to expose factories and connectors to applications on the backup node in order to connect to the live server.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar architecture two clients (jboss) and cluster of HornetQ (2xlive, 2xbackup) biuld using standalone HornetQ.

At first we tried to connect in the way as you described but it never went ok through anomaly tests.

The solutions was:
Setup discovery group at hornetq (hornetq-configuration.xml):

```
  <discovery-groups>
     <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
        <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
     </discovery-group>
  </discovery-groups>
```

Then on client side (we use spring) define discoveryGroupConfig:

```
 <bean id="discoveryGroupConfig" class="org.hornetq.api.core.DiscoveryGroupConfiguration">
    <constructor-arg name="groupAddress" value="231.7.7.7" />
    <constructor-arg name="groupPort" value="9876" />
    <property name="discoveryInitialWaitTimeout" value="10000"/>
</bean>
```

the factory:

```
 <bean id="producerDiscoveryConnFactory" class="org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQXAConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="true" />
    <constructor-arg ref="discoveryGroupConfig" />
</bean>
```

and in final the caching factory:

```
<bean id="cachingConnFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="producerDiscoveryConnFactory" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="200" />
    <property name="cacheProducers" value="true" />
</bean>
```

But you should be aware that: JMS connection is always tied to a given node in a cluster once created. So you need to listen to topology by implementing the interface org.hornetq.api.core.client.ClusterTopologyListener and recycle the spring MessageListenerContainers:

```
public interface ClusterTopologyListener
 {
     void nodeUP(long eventUID, String nodeID,               Pair<TransportConfiguration, TransportConfiguration> connectorPair, boolean last);

   void nodeDown(long eventUID, String nodeID);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you configure hornetq server as backup by adding `<backup>true</backup>` with other configurations, that server does not create factories, queues and you cannot deploy JMS components referring that. 
Try leaving all the other configurations as it is and change `<backup>false</backup>`.

[hornetq manual: high availability section](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.4.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html_single/#ha)